# Get favicon from webview UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, favicon

I have a question: how do I get the favicon of a page displayed in a webview in C# UWP?
I want to store the icon to access it later. Is there any way of doing that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I did the following:

```
Uri icoURI = new Uri("https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=" + WebPageView.Source);
currentTab.IconSource = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.BitmapIconSource() { UriSource = icoURI, ShowAsMonochrome = false };
```

Answer (score 2):

> Get favicon from webview UWP

There is `shortcut icon` rel attribute in html that use to describe favicon. And you could use WebView `InvokeScriptAsync` to inject detected method into eval function and use `window.external.notify` pass favicon's href back.

**For example**

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    MyWebView.LoadCompleted += MyWebView_LoadCompleted;
}

private async void MyWebView_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     string functionString = @"var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName ('link');
for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++)
{
    if ((nodeList[i].getAttribute('rel') == 'icon') || (nodeList[i].getAttribute('rel') == 'shortcut icon'))
    {
        favicon = nodeList[i].getAttribute('href');
        window.external.notify(favicon); 
    }
}";

 await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });

}

private void MyWebView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
   var url = e.Value;
}
```

**Please note**

Allowed [sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify) are specified in the Content URIs section of Package.appxmanifest and cannot contain domain wildcards and must be https .

[image]

And this is [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/GetFavTest) that you could refer.

Comment: Thank you for the help! But, I already solved it and forgot to update.