# Get WebView2 page's favicon and display it as the icon of a TabView

Tags: c#, favicon, winui-3

I'm making a WinUI 3 web browser in C# and am trying to get the favicon of the page my WebView2 is displaying. Then I can put it as the icon of the currently selected tab. I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62349920) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62328267/get-favicon-from-webview-uwp), and modified the code to work for me:

```cs
Uri icoURI = new("https://t0.gstatic.com/faviconV2?client=SOCIAL&type=FAVICON&fallback_opts=TYPE,SIZE,URL&url=" + Variables.webViews[MainWindow.selectedBrowsingTabIndex].Source);
(MainWindow.browsingTabsStatic.SelectedItem as TabViewItem).IconSource = new BitmapIconSource() { UriSource = icoURI, ShowAsMonochrome = false };
```

This doesn't work very well--it throws random exceptions when I try to use the `WebView2` in other locations, takes a while to load and display the icon, and doesn't work for sites Google hasn't indexed.

Is there an alternative that works on all sites and is decently fast and reliable?

Answer (score 3):

A site can define a Favicon (or not) using many ways, so here is a code that directly uses WebView2's **FavIcon features**: the [FaviconChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.faviconchanged) the [FaviconUri Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.faviconuri) and the [GetFaviconAsync() Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.getfaviconasync).

So you can just use this:

```
tabViewItem.IconSource = new BitmapIconSource
{
    UriSource = new Uri(MyWebView.CoreWebView2.FaviconUri),
    ShowAsMonochrome = false,
};
```

I've been one step further in my context, as I wanted to use the favicon for the application icon too. This uses WinUI3's [AppWindow.SetIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.windowing.appwindow.seticon) method.

The tricky part is `AppWindow.SetIcon` only supports a file path to a **.ico** format file while WebView2 only support **PNG** or **JPG** streams. Luckily, .ico files can be encoded using PNG bytes (since Windows Vista).

Xaml:

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox x:Name="url" />
        <Button x:Name="navigate" Click="navigate_Click">Go</Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <controls:WebView2
        x:Name="MyWebView"
        Grid.Row="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

</Grid>
```

C#:

In the following code, I avoid rewriting the .ico for a given `favicon uri` each time it changes but this is up to you.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MyWebView.NavigationCompleted += MyWebView_NavigationCompleted;
}

private async void navigate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await MyWebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
    MyWebView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(url.Text);
}

private void MyWebView_NavigationCompleted(WebView2 sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    // unhook from ourselves, we shouldn't need it anymore
    MyWebView.NavigationCompleted -= MyWebView_NavigationCompleted;
    
    // hook on favicon changes
    MyWebView.CoreWebView2.FaviconChanged += (s, e) => _ = UpdateFavicon();

    // first time set
    _ = UpdateFavicon();
}

private async ValueTask UpdateFavicon()
{
    var uri = MyWebView.CoreWebView2.FaviconUri;

    // in your TabViewItem case, this is where you would do
    // tabViewItem.IconSource = new BitmapIconSource...

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri))
    {
        // Note: when the site has no favicon (like with www.example.com),
        // uri is the empty string and GetFaviconAsync will return an 
        // "undefined" icon stream that can still be used to save a .ico.
        // Here I just remove the icon but we could continue
        // and use this "undefined" icon instead.
        AppWindow.SetIcon(null);
        return;
    }

    // come up with a unique (cache) file path
    using var md5 = MD5.Create();
    var name = new Guid(md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(uri))) + ".ico";
    var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), name);

    // don't rewrite if already there
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        // get PNG bytes
        using var iconStream = await MyWebView.CoreWebView2.GetFaviconAsync(CoreWebView2FaviconImageFormat.Png);

        // write to memory (shouldn't be too big)
        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using var stream = iconStream.AsStream();
        await stream.CopyToAsync(ms);
        stream.Position = 0;

        // decode it to determine width & height
        // seems WebView2 sends always 16x16 streams but not sure it's contractual
        var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(ms.AsRandomAccessStream());

        // write icon in PNG format
        WritePNGIcon(path, decoder.PixelWidth, decoder.PixelHeight, ms.ToArray());
    }
    AppWindow.SetIcon(path);
}

public static void WritePNGIcon(string iconFilePath, uint width, uint height, byte[] pngBytes, int pngBytesIndex = 0, int pngBytesCount = int.MaxValue)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(iconFilePath);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(pngBytes);
    using var stream = File.OpenWrite(iconFilePath);
    WritePNGIcon(stream, width, height, pngBytes, pngBytesIndex, pngBytesCount);
}

public static void WritePNGIcon(Stream iconFileStream, uint width, uint height, byte[] pngBytes, int pngBytesIndex = 0, int pngBytesCount = int.MaxValue)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(iconFileStream);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(pngBytes);
    if (pngBytesCount == int.MaxValue || pngBytesCount < 0)
    {
        pngBytesCount = pngBytes.Length;
    }

    var startPos = iconFileStream.Position;
    var writer = new BinaryWriter(iconFileStream);
    writer.Write((short)0); // reserved
    writer.Write((short)1); // image type (1 for .ico)
    writer.Write((short)1); // count
    const int maxIconSize = 256;
    writer.Write(width == maxIconSize ? (byte)0 : (byte)width);
    writer.Write(height == maxIconSize ? (byte)0 : (byte)height);
    writer.Write((byte)0); // number of colors in the color palette
    writer.Write((byte)0); // reserved
    writer.Write((short)1); // color planes
    writer.Write((short)32); // bits per pixel (ARGB=32)

    var offsets = iconFileStream.Position;
    writer.Write(0); // size of image data, we'll rewrite that later
    writer.Write(0); // offset of data from beginning;

    var pngOffset = iconFileStream.Position - startPos;
    writer.Write(pngBytes, pngBytesIndex, pngBytesCount);

    // save end position
    var endPos = iconFileStream.Position;
    iconFileStream.Seek(offsets, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    writer.Write(pngBytesCount);
    writer.Write((int)pngOffset);
    iconFileStream.Position = endPos; // restore end position
}
```

Results on [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com):

[image]

Note: the .ico path can also be used as the `UriSource` for the `TabViewItem`.